# Replacing more than one escape character when labeling in ArcMap using VBscript?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, vbscript, labeling

I have written a label expression to match font color to the symbology for a point file based on unique values. Problem is, occasionally the comments will include one or the other special characters ("&" or "<"). Sometimes there can be hundreds of points per map that may or may not contain those special characters.

I have replaced one of the escape characters using the snippet:

```
function findLabel([FORESTER],[NAME]):
NewString = Replace( [NAME] ,"<","&lt;")  
if([FORESTER] = "AG") then
    findLabel = "<CLR red= '211' green='255' blue='190'>"&NewString&"</CLR>"
elseif ([FORESTER] = "RS") then
    findLabel = "<CLR red= '76' green='230' blue='0'>"&NewString&"</CLR>"
```

But how do I write the code to replace 2 values in the same variable?

Comment: Try this: NewString =Replace( Replace( [NAME] ,"<","&lt;"), ,">","&gt;")

Comment: thanks, I tried this earlier and it wouldn't work. I gave it a second shot switching the order and "poof." it works. go figure.
Originally, I had the "<" replaced first and the "&" second.  I switched the order so that the ampersand was replaced first and now it works.